# How to call an IronPython 2 method from C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I can get an IronPython 2 class back to my C#.  What is the new IronPython 2 way of calling a member on that class?

```
object ironPythonClass = scope.GetVariable("Hamish");
object[] args = new object[0];
object pythonObject = engine.Operations.Call(ironPythonClass, args);

var member = "Home";
// old way IronPython 1
// var methodResult = Ops.Invoke(this.pythonObject, SymbolTable.StringToId(member), args);
```

I thought all I'd have to do was

```
var methodResult = PythonOps.Invoke(codeContext, pythonObject, SymbolTable.StringToId(member), args);
```

but creating a dummy CodeContext doesn't seem to be right.  I feel as though I should be able to derive one from my

```
code.Execute();
```

that runs the Python file creating the class, plus the scope that arises out of that execution.

Answer (score 3):

Found a way to do it:

```
var ops = engine.Operations;
var x = ops.GetMember(pythonObject, member);
var h = ops.Call(x, new object[0]);
```

Looks like the Operations produces an OperationsObject which has useful members.

Looking at the DLR code (Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting) however I see that Call is deprecated:

```
[Obsolete("Use Invoke instead")]
public object Call(object obj, params object[] parameters) {
    return _ops.Invoke(obj, parameters);
}
```

My version of scripting 0.9.20209, doesn't yet have the Invoke however.

After updating to the newer IronPython 2.6Beta and its scripting dlls I find I can write:

```
var h = ops.InvokeMember(pythonObject, member, new object[0]);
```

Comment: Updated to the 2.6 beta with newer scripting dlls - I can now write:

    var h = ops.InvokeMember(pythonObject, member, new object[0]);